# Influence of Spanish and usage of Spanish words in US English

Tags: etymology, american-english, word-usage, spanish, reference

A recent report by Instituto Cervantes [["*El Español una lengua viva, informe 2015*"]](http://eldiae.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/espanol_lengua-viva_20151.pdf) lists the US as the 4th country in the world with the highest number of native Spanish speakers (41.343.921), following closely behind Spain (42.982.862), and Colombia (47.630.575), with Mexico (117.133.629) as the undisputed leader. The definition of *native speaker* used in the report might be conservative: [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2015/jun/29/us-second-biggest-spanish-speaking-country) surveyed the report placing the US right after Mexico. But regardless of the measure you choose, these figures indicate that the number of native Spanish speakers in the US is considerable.

In spite of those numbers, many native Spanish speakers from Spain (including me) know very little about the influence of Spanish in US English. In fact, in school and high school, most of us do not study any variant of American English at all because our system favors British English.

There exists a Wikipedia article [*List of English words of
    Spanish origin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Spanish_origin) but it does not say anything about usage: for instance, it gives no information about whether certain Spanish words are used in the US but mostly on certain states (say, in New Mexico, California, Texas or Arizona, which have the highest concentrations of native Spanish speakers).

I'm sure many native Spanish speakers such as myself would like to discover more about  this interesting subject:

**Question 1.** Are there good pedagogical resources   (books, online lecture notes, wikis, etc) to learn about the influence of Spanish in modern American English in the US? I am interested in pedagogical reviews, not in research level papers.

**Question 2.** How do north Americans view [Spanglish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanglish)?  Have there been attempts to suppress this phenomenon in the US?

Comment: A good place to start is *Google Scholar*  I entered the search term, **Spanish words US English**, and found this ---> https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=Spanish+words+US+English&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5

Comment: Isn't Google Scholar better for research level references? My question is about pedagogical texts. I will mention that explicitly in my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: http://spanish.about.com/cs/historyofspanish/a/spanishloanword.htm and a pie chart showing the percentage of loanwords from different countries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_by_country_or_language_of_origin

Comment: This is an interesting question, but one that is likely to be closed because the site discourages list questions. I think you'll find, though, that outside of terms for food and a couple of other items (the Chevy vehicle *El Camino* comes to mind), Spanish and English tend not to mix much in the USA. Spanish remains, unfortunately, an underclass language throughout much of the country.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to improve the question to make it fit to the site? In cs.theory stack exchange big list questions are actually on topic though there is a policy to make them community wiki. Would that be possible here?

Comment: We don't always realize they're loan-words when we use them, e.g. **hoosegow**.

Comment: Also, I am not sure this is a "big list question". That actually depends on the amount of available resources at the moment. I was not very successful with Google search. I would gladly implement suggestions to improve the question :)

Comment: You could use commas (or just spaces) between the groups of three in your large numbers. But it's the type of question, not the way you've asked it, that's unsuitable for ELU. It's either a request for resources, or far too broad ('How many loanwords from Spanish do you know?') It's a great question, but perhaps for the SE 'linguistics' site or some other.

Comment: I see. What if I make the question more specific by asking only about the existence of dictionaries / glossaries? That is interesting enough for me at the moment.

Comment: Your suggestion to move to lingüistics might be good though :) I did not know this site well enough to know if its on topic. I will wait to gather more feedback.

Comment: I think if you asked this as a question merely about the influence of Spanish in American English you would be fine. Remove the question about resources (you'll get links to those anyway when people post responses).

Comment: @Robusto. Thanks for the feedback. But I am not sure I understand you: if I remove the resource part then the question becomes ill defined and broader.

Comment: Also, could someone maybe give me a link to the no-reference question policy of the site? I tried to find it without success in the SE [\[tour\]](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and in the meta site.

Comment: Note that there are two separate things going on here:  First, American English has absorbed a number of Spanish words (including "dollar") over the centuries.  British English has no doubt done the same, though probably to a lesser degree.  Second, the US has a large population of "Hispanic" individuals who speak Spanish as their primary language, or at least as a major secondary language.  In areas where the HIspanic population is high one thus develops what's known as "Spanglish", a combination of the two languages, and words are swapped back and forth fairly freely. But only in those areas

Comment: @JuanBermejoVega: You might try coming to ELU chat and talking with tchrist there. None better for answering [word list](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23521491#23521491) questions, especially regarding Spanish. [Direct Link to ELU Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage).

Comment: [Jane Hill's paper on "Mock Spanish"](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic653576.files/Language%20Race%20and%20White%20Public%20Space.pdf) covers the socioeconomic and racist aspects of Spanish in American English.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who participated in the discussion for providing helpful feedback. Since the discussion is not being productive anymore and my interest is on references, I will try to find a different Stack Exchange site where reference-request type questions on English Language & Usage are on topic. I will leave the question here to be closed as off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although I personally find it interesting, OP has indicated this is his present preference, and because it is more likely to find a home on Linguistics.SE.

Comment: English speakers in the US show, for the most part, very little serious interest in learning any real Spanish.

Comment: @aparente001 Los hay que sí, los hay que no.

Comment: @tchrist - I visited Brownsville, TX, once, and found it to be truly bilingual (at least, at that time), and the coloring of the person, and the way they pronounced English, had nothing to do with their degree of comfort in, or preference, for talking in Spanish -- everyone I met could move fluidly back and forth.  But judging from other places in the US I've been to, that is the exception rather than the rule.  ---  My point is to try to explain why the OP and the commenters have not found the sort of resources the OP was looking for.

Comment: The edit attempts to keep the question on topic, although arguably it's become more opinion-based. If the OP dislikes my "mutilation" they can rollback to version #1 or #2

Comment: Mari-Lou A, thanks a lot for the edit. I like your edits because they keep the question on topic, which will be more useful to others. Just to clarify, my original interest was not on Spanglish but more on Spanish words that are now used by modern native English speakers e.g. [amigo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amigo), [cargo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo), [patio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patio), [barrio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrio).

Comment: Thank you for telling me my edit was not harmful, I don't normally do such radical editing but I wanted to keep it on topic. As for the Spanglish question it is connected to your request about Spanish loanwords, the aim being that you receive some interesting answers along with references and resources.

Comment: I wasn't notified that you had left a message for me, I just revisited the question to see what had happened. Glad to see it's still open! Whenever somebody leaves a comment the OP will receive a notification in their inbox, but when an OP needs to communicate (also called *ping*) with a user, and between different users, they have to write: @+username

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27504/discussion-on-question-by-juan-bermejo-vega-influence-of-spanish-and-usage-of-sp).

Comment: If you google for Spanish influence on or Spanish in American English you find some websites.

Answer (score 2):

Having lived most of my life in the American Southwest, I feel I can answer based on pure immersion and observation.

**Question 1:** I don't personally know of any resources where you can learn about Spanish influences, other than talking to people who live with both Spanish and English.  My parents, my in-laws, and my wife all speak Spanish, and just through pure observation, you can see that Spanish has had a few influences on English.

For example: the words *fiesta* and *siesta* are commonly used without being translated.  In Albuquerque, New Mexico, we have a famous gathering of hot air balloon enthusiasts called the Albuquerque Balloon Fiesta.  This is considered normal usage of the word *fiesta*, even though strict English grammar would require that you translate *fiesta* into *party* or something similar.  *Fiesta* sounds better to the locals, and it is the word of choice to describe this gathering.

In a similar manner, *siesta*, with its connotation deriving from Mexican siestas, can sometimes be viewed derogatorily as a lazy break or nap when one should be working.  This derogatory connotation stems from the stereotype of the lazy Mexican.  The lazy Mexican stereotype comes from Americans seeing Mexican people taking their siestas during the hottest part of the day (Northern Mexico has a lot of desert areas, and is closest to the American-Mexican border).  Once the heat relented, the Mexicans would get up and continue their daily activities.  But Americans saw this as laziness, because they view a work day as a monolithic chuck of time with minimal breaks.  But the negative connotation with *siesta* stuck, and is still associated with the word to this day.

Words that have just been borrowed from Spanish include Mexican food names, such as *taco* and *burrito*, and words that express feelings, such as *pronto* and *andale*.  Street names in the American Southwest are commonly named after people and places with Spanish names that the local English-only speakers just have to learn to pronounce (such as *Juan Tabo* or *Montaño*).  Taco Bell is particularly guilty of slaughtering Spanish with food names like *chalupa* and *quesarito*.  Even to this day, *jalapeño* is still pronounced *ha-la-peen-yo*, which comes close to the correct pronunciation, but still falls laughingly short.

**Question 2:** Spanglish is generally evil.  No, I'm kidding.  But it is my experience that most people who respect both English and Spanish *hate* Spanglish.  The common refrain from people who hate Spanglish is "English or Spanish, choose one."  With good reason, of course: grammatically speaking, no one should express themselves in two languages at the same time.  But the truth is that people who live with multiple languages may have been introduced to new concepts in only one language.  Subconciously, those concepts belong to those languages.  So Spanglish is a side-effect of knowing certain concepts only in English or Spanish.

For example, there is a habit of Spanish speakers to end English sentences with the Spanish word *mejor*.  This is actually a shortcut: you can express that it is better to do something in a particular way by using the word *mejor* at the end of your sentence.  Most people understand what you mean.  But short-cutting one language through another that particularly annoys fluent speakers of both languages.  Yes, you may have to use more than one word in one of the languages, but at least you are not expressing yourself in multiple languages at the same time.

There is an even worse phenomenon in *Northern New Mexico* (note: **not** *Northern Mexico*) where English words are pronounced with Spanish rules and accents.  Imagine pronouncing the English word *brake* with Spanish rules and accents: it would be the equivalent of an imaginary word in Spanish spelled *braque*.  This is a generally reviled version of Spanglish outside of Northern New Mexico.

The best way to know about these things is to actually live and talk to the people here.  The citizens of California, Arizona, New Mexico, and Texas are the best resources for finding out how Spanish has influenced American English, because they deal with both languages the most.