# Spanish-derived words in English

Tags: etymology, loanwords, spanish, list-request

I recently found out that "mustang" is a <s>Hispanicism</s> word of Spanish origin: it is adapted from "mostrengo" or "mestreño", which roughly mean "without rooting"; Merriam-Webster compiles "mesteño" (where 'ñ' sounds as the 'gn' in 'lasagna') as "runaway cattle".

Since large portions of the southern USA used to be first under Spanish, then under Mexican, rule, I wonder if there are other "proper" English words that are <s>hispanicisms</s>. I certainly do not mean words like "sombrero", "taco" or "tamal(e)", which are just calques of words in currently spoken Spanish; neither do I mean words like "concentration", whose etymology in both English and Spanish is Latin. I mean words in English whose etymology is original from Spanish. Specifically, I'd like to know if there are (US) English words, like "mustang" above, that are still colloquially used nowadays but derive from archaic Spanish.

[Wikipedia doesn't return much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanicisms_in_English), I regret to say. I found [this question here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267824/influence-of-spanish-and-usage-of-spanish-words-in-us-english), but it is mostly a harangue on Spanglish. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Colorado.  Texas.  Arizona.  California. Nevada.

Comment: Hoosegow. Lariat.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but as a reminder, requests for examples, suggestions, or other open-ended lists are ill-suited to the Stack Exchange Q&A format, which designates a single authoritative answer. Every response in a list request is equally valid, so the "best" answer is a matter of personal whim rather than quality. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and to review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: _Taco_ etc are not calques, they are straight borrowings. Calques are loan-translations, where a word is analysed, the parts translated, and the results put together into a new word. Calquing is not very common in English, but an example which will at least be comprehensible to English speakers is _insect_, where the Latin root  _īnsectum_ was a calque of the Greek _ἔντομον,_ both meaning "cut in", i.e. a body divided into sections. (Edit): _gospel_ is an Old English example of a calque: _God-spel_ ("good message") from Greek _εὐαγγέλιον_.

Comment: Does *tortilla* count? Its meaning in the Americas has changed quite a bit from its meaning in European Spanish.

Comment: Well, "tortilla" is a Spanish word, so I think it falls outside the scope of my question.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Spanish_origin) -- its list of English words of Spanish origin -- has more of what you seek.

BTW words such as "Hispanicism" aren't generally used to mean words of the sort you seek. Rather, Hispanicisms are those characteristic ways in which the English of those whose first language is Spanish differs from the English of native speakers.

Comment: I hadn't seen that one. Thanks! Glad to learn that "Hispanicism" is a false cognate :)

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few; unfortunately only a few come to mind immediately.  I'm sure I will wake up in the middle of the night with more.

[**Hoosegow**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hoosegow), meaning "jail" (as opposed to prison) used to be a staple of cowboy/Western fiction; it's derived from Spanish *juzgado*.

[**Calaboose**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calaboose) also means "jail" and is also mostly obsolete except for Western novels; it's derived from *calabozo* "dungeon". (Thanks to @MichaelHarvey for the reminder.)

[**Tornado**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tornado) is apparently derived from Spanish *tronado*, "thunderstorm" - since both the definition AND spelling have shifted, I find it more interesting than most borrowings.

[**Lariat**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lariat) - a rope with a running noose used to catch livestock - is derived from Spanish *la reata*.

[**Renegade**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renegade) comes from Spanish *renegado* (same meaning), but is occasionally given the false etymology "runagate".  This one is a straight borrowing, so may not meet your requirements.

[**Ranch**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ranch), from *rancho*, is another straight borrowing, but is so common in American English that it's easy to forget it was borrowed.

[**Buckaroo**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buckaroo), from *vaquero* (thanks @Robusto!) means "cowboy", but these days it's more commonly applied to kids:  "Buckle up, buckaroos!"

Comment: I'll see your hoosegow and raise you calaboose.

Comment: Let's not forget *buckaroo*, from Sp. *vaquero*.

Comment: I never made that connection!  Who could forget _The Adventures of Buckaroo Banzai Across the 8th Dimension_?!

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to add any others that occur; this was a fun question (_pace_ @choster).

Comment: Arroyo - a wash, gulch or dry creek.